# How to convert cURL response into array

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

Hello I am trying to get the response from the cURL call to stack exchange api and want to convert the json response into a php array, is there a example code to show how to get this converted.

Comment: `json_decode()` buddy...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode()` on the json object.

I highly recommand to give `true` in the second arg:

```php
$php_object = json_decode($api_response, true);
```

True give you an associative array. I think it's useful for your case